# how does image hover change colour

Tags: css

I'm trying to hover over an image and would like to to change its colour when hovered.

My HTML is:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">
  <div id="wrap"><img src="img/plan1.png" alt=""></div>
</a>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal xlarge" data-reveal>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
  position:relative; 
}

#wrap:hover     {
  position:relative; 
  border: blue;
}
```

Some one please help, I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: This can only be achieved by JavaScript. You should search for some scripts that dynamically edit image colors or apply filters to them.

Comment: I did't understand your question completely..
What is your picture ??? What colour should change ???
Border colour or a colour in image??

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Answer (score 1):

See the following fiddle here.

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img:hover 
{
    border:solid 2px blue;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/70e8h6z1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the hover status of the link, not of the div.

CSS:

```
a:hover #wrap img{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Or if you'd like to have a filter on your image (not fully supported)

```
a:hover #wrap img{
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```